# Nonlinear Functional Equation $f(x)^{2}=f\left(\frac x a\right)$

Tags: analysis, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f(x)$ such for a given fixed $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the following functional equation holds:
> $$f(x)^{2}=f\left(\frac x a\right)$$

I'm not sure  how to solve this equation other then using the method of power series, any tips?

Comment: How would you use power series here? It is not even given $\;f\;$ is continuous, leave along differentiable.

Comment: @Timbuc A solution can proceed by finding a solution of certain form and then later proving that the solution is unique.

Comment: True but In general if you have no idea if the function is continuous or not  it can be a good idea to see if you can guess a solution a candidate solution using power series to get a recurrence relation with the coefficients then show that this candidate solution does in fact hold.

Comment: $f(x) = c\cdot \exp(\frac{x}{2a})$ for any $c$ is one family of solutions.

Comment: @jef That is not a solution, RHS is $exp(\frac{x}{a})$ the LHS is $exp(\frac{x}{2a^{2}})$ these are not the same.
The equation is nonlinear you do not have that if $f(x)$ is a solution then so is $cf(x)$ unless $c=1$

Comment: @lancewellton Right, I made a computation mistake. For $a = \frac{1}{2}$, $\exp$ is a solution. For other values of $a$, exponentials do not appear to work.

Comment: @jef Just out of curiosity how did you arrive at your answer?

Comment: I mistakenly solved $\exp(2tx) = \exp(\frac{x}{a})$, forgetting the $t$ on the right. Another way to see the case when $a=\frac{1}{2}$ is that $f$ must be a homomorphism from the group $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}, \times)$ to the group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$. Perhaps this view sheds light on other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will describe 2 trivial functions and one nontrivial family of functions satisfying the above relation for each $a$. I will give this answer even though I am not finding *all* such functions because nobody else has provided an answer in a day.

First let $c = \frac{1}{a}$. I think it's more natural to think about the equation as $f(x)^2 = f(cx)$ than as in the OP. Clearly $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ are solutions.

More interestingly, the family of functions
$$f(x) = p^{(qx)^{\log_c(2)}}$$
for any $p, q > 0$ satisfies the inequality, which we can see as follows:

$$f(x)^2 = p^{2\cdot (qx)^{log_c(2)}} = 2^{c^{\log_c(2)} (qx)^{\log_c(2)}} = p^{(q(cx))^{\log_c(2)}} = f(cx).$$

This approach immediately generalizes to solve equations of the form
$$f(x)^n = f(cx),$$
with solution
$$f(x) = p^{(qx)^{\log_c(n)}}.$$